# Adjusting the width of a table view dynamically in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tableview

Im getting a json response from the server and displaying it in the table view.I have displayed the data by creating a custom cell.

In  app now i want to adjust the width of a table view from the app.

ie for example just like we adjust the width of a cell in microsoft excel sheet.

[image]
Can anyone please help me to do this.Thanks in advance

Comment: In iPhone a UITableView is an object with a fixed width that covers the full width of the screen. It doesn't really make sense to change the width of it and it would go against the Apple HIG. Can you explain a bit about what you are wanting to achieve.

Comment: @Fogmeister if suppose the content is too large,usually it will tuncate the tail.so my client want should be able to move the cell horizontally so that he can see the full content.Same in case of a excel sheet

Comment: That's not how a UITableView works. First you should try to make content succinct so that it doesn't truncate. Second, there is no "horizontal scroll". Third, if the content is longer than the table width then wrap the text and change the row height so that it all fits. The user should never have to scroll horizontally to see all the text.

Comment: Can you post some code? Like @Fogmeister said, you can change the height of an UITableViewCell by dynamically calculating the height of your text and setting that in the UITableViewDelegate method, - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Answer (score 0):

try putting your data into multiple lines,

or you can put a text view onto cell, and put the data in that

Answer (score 0):

As everyone says, you should look for a better option.

Anyway if it's really what you want to do, I would suggest to create a tableview as large as you need and then embed it in a scrollView. 
Notify the tableView that it shouldn't scroll (the scrollView will do the job).
Set the contentSize of the scrollView to the size of the tableView and its frame to the size of the screen.
If you want to tap on the tableViewCell, you may need to add a gestureRecognizer (search on StackOverflow for the method)

Answer (score 0):

First, you can change the UITableView's width
when it finished to change the width, reload it with new Cells with new width.